Getting UnexpectedStatusException while training linear model in AWS Sagemaker?
I am trying to train linear-model in AWS sagemaker, where predictor type is "regressor".
I am stuck I have no clue what I have to do.
I have uploaded my data to S3-bucket.
CONCLUSION:
 UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job
 LR-v1-2024-06-16-05-01-56-352: Failed. Reason: ClientError: No
 iterator has been registered for ContentType ('csv', '1.0'), exit
 code: 2

while doing training in sagemaker. My data is in correct format. i.e
target_variable then other features. As per best of my knowledge.
How to solve this particular issue, what mistakes in code will lead us
to this error. Is this related to AWS settings also?
Bellow is the code to upload data in S3-bucket in required format.
def export_data_lr(data, name, pre):
    # split data into X and y subsets
    X = data.drop(columns="price")
    y = data.price.copy()
    
    
    # transformation
    X = pre.transform(X)
    
    file_name = get_file_name_lr(name)
    (
         y
        . to_frame()
        .join(X)
        .to_csv(file_name, index=False, header=False)
    )

def upload_to_bucket_lr(name,BUCKET_NAME):
    file_name = get_file_name_lr(name)
    
    (
        boto3
        .Session()
        .resource("s3")
        .Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        .Object(os.path.join(DATA_PREFIX, f"{name}/{name}-lr.csv"))
        .upload_file(file_name)
    )

Upto here every thing is working fine. Data is correctly uploaded to S3-bucket without any problem.
In my s3-bucket i am able to see my training, testing and validation data.
Bellow is code for building linear-learner model with predictor type is "regressor".
I am not using much hyperparameters for shake of simplicity.
from sagemaker import image_uris
def return_lr_model(sagemaker,BUCKET_NAME,algorithm,version):
    
    OUTPUT_PATH = get_output_path(BUCKET_NAME)
    region = sagemaker.Session().boto_region_name
    session = sagemaker.Session()
    role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
    image_uri = image_uris.retrieve(region=boto3.Session().region_name, framework="linear-learner")
    
    lr_model = Estimator(
        image_uri = image_uri,
        role = role,
        instance_count = 1,
        instance_type = "ml.m4.xlarge",
        output_path = OUTPUT_PATH,
        sagemaker_session = session,
        base_job_name = 'LR-v1')
    return lr_model

def perform_hyperparameter(lr_model):
    lr_model.set_hyperparameters(
        feature_dim = "auto",
        predictor_type = "regressor",
        normalize_data = False,
        epochs = 15
    )
    return lr_model

def create_lr_model(sagemaker,BUCKET_NAME,algorithm,version):
    lr_model = return_lr_model(sagemaker,BUCKET_NAME,algorithm,version)
    lr_model =  perform_hyperparameter(lr_model)
    return lr_model

lr_model = create_lr_model(sagemaker,BUCKET_NAME,algorithm,version)

Code to create data channel
def get_data_channels(train,val):
    train = get_file_name_lr(train)
    bucket_path = f"s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{DATA_PREFIX}/train/{train}"
    train_data_channel = TrainingInput(bucket_path, content_type="csv")
    
    val = get_file_name_lr(val)
    bucket_path = f"s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{DATA_PREFIX}/val/{val}"
    val_data_channel = TrainingInput(bucket_path, content_type="text/csv")
    
    data_channels = {
        "train": train_data_channel,
        "validation": val_data_channel
    }
    
    return data_channels

data_channel = get_data_channels("train","val")

Train Model:
lr_model.fit(data_channel)

Here my actual problem starts, bellow is error which I am encountering while training the model:
INFO:sagemaker:Creating training-job with name: LR-v1-2024-06-16-05-01-56-352
2024-06-16 05:01:56 Starting - Starting the training job...
2024-06-16 05:02:17 Starting - Preparing the instances for training...
2024-06-16 05:02:48 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2024-06-16 05:03:23 Downloading - Downloading the training image.........
2024-06-16 05:04:29 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress..Docker entrypoint called with argument(s): train
Running default environment configuration script
[06/16/2024 05:04:54 INFO 140601654445888] Reading default configuration from /opt/amazon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/algorithm/resources/default-input.json: {'mini_batch_size': '1000', 'epochs': '15', 'feature_dim': 'auto', 'use_bias': 'true', 'binary_classifier_model_selection_criteria': 'accuracy', 'f_beta': '1.0', 'target_recall': '0.8', 'target_precision': '0.8', 'num_models': 'auto', 'num_calibration_samples': '10000000', 'init_method': 'uniform', 'init_scale': '0.07', 'init_sigma': '0.01', 'init_bias': '0.0', 'optimizer': 'auto', 'loss': 'auto', 'margin': '1.0', 'quantile': '0.5', 'loss_insensitivity': '0.01', 'huber_delta': '1.0', 'num_classes': '1', 'accuracy_top_k': '3', 'wd': 'auto', 'l1': 'auto', 'momentum': 'auto', 'learning_rate': 'auto', 'beta_1': 'auto', 'beta_2': 'auto', 'bias_lr_mult': 'auto', 'bias_wd_mult': 'auto', 'use_lr_scheduler': 'true', 'lr_scheduler_step': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_factor': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_minimum_lr': 'auto', 'positive_example_weight_mult': '1.0', 'balance_multiclass_weights': 'false', 'normalize_data': 'true', 'normalize_label': 'auto', 'unbias_data': 'auto', 'unbias_label': 'auto', 'num_point_for_scaler': '10000', '_kvstore': 'auto', '_num_gpus': 'auto', '_num_kv_servers': 'auto', '_log_level': 'info', '_tuning_objective_metric': '', 'early_stopping_patience': '3', 'early_stopping_tolerance': '0.001', '_enable_profiler': 'false'}
[06/16/2024 05:04:54 INFO 140601654445888] Merging with provided configuration from /opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json: {'epochs': '15', 'feature_dim': 'auto', 'normalize_data': 'False', 'predictor_type': 'regressor'}
[06/16/2024 05:04:54 INFO 140601654445888] Final configuration: {'mini_batch_size': '1000', 'epochs': '15', 'feature_dim': 'auto', 'use_bias': 'true', 'binary_classifier_model_selection_criteria': 'accuracy', 'f_beta': '1.0', 'target_recall': '0.8', 'target_precision': '0.8', 'num_models': 'auto', 'num_calibration_samples': '10000000', 'init_method': 'uniform', 'init_scale': '0.07', 'init_sigma': '0.01', 'init_bias': '0.0', 'optimizer': 'auto', 'loss': 'auto', 'margin': '1.0', 'quantile': '0.5', 'loss_insensitivity': '0.01', 'huber_delta': '1.0', 'num_classes': '1', 'accuracy_top_k': '3', 'wd': 'auto', 'l1': 'auto', 'momentum': 'auto', 'learning_rate': 'auto', 'beta_1': 'auto', 'beta_2': 'auto', 'bias_lr_mult': 'auto', 'bias_wd_mult': 'auto', 'use_lr_scheduler': 'true', 'lr_scheduler_step': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_factor': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_minimum_lr': 'auto', 'positive_example_weight_mult': '1.0', 'balance_multiclass_weights': 'false', 'normalize_data': 'False', 'normalize_label': 'auto', 'unbias_data': 'auto', 'unbias_label': 'auto', 'num_point_for_scaler': '10000', '_kvstore': 'auto', '_num_gpus': 'auto', '_num_kv_servers': 'auto', '_log_level': 'info', '_tuning_objective_metric': '', 'early_stopping_patience': '3', 'early_stopping_tolerance': '0.001', '_enable_profiler': 'false', 'predictor_type': 'regressor'}
/opt/amazon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mxnet/model.py:97: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if num_device is 1 and 'dist' not in kvstore:
/opt/amazon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py:495: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if cons['type'] is 'ineq':
/opt/amazon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_shgo.py:743: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if len(self.X_min) is not 0:
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 WARNING 140601654445888] Loggers have already been setup.
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 INFO 140601654445888] Final configuration: {'mini_batch_size': '1000', 'epochs': '15', 'feature_dim': 'auto', 'use_bias': 'true', 'binary_classifier_model_selection_criteria': 'accuracy', 'f_beta': '1.0', 'target_recall': '0.8', 'target_precision': '0.8', 'num_models': 'auto', 'num_calibration_samples': '10000000', 'init_method': 'uniform', 'init_scale': '0.07', 'init_sigma': '0.01', 'init_bias': '0.0', 'optimizer': 'auto', 'loss': 'auto', 'margin': '1.0', 'quantile': '0.5', 'loss_insensitivity': '0.01', 'huber_delta': '1.0', 'num_classes': '1', 'accuracy_top_k': '3', 'wd': 'auto', 'l1': 'auto', 'momentum': 'auto', 'learning_rate': 'auto', 'beta_1': 'auto', 'beta_2': 'auto', 'bias_lr_mult': 'auto', 'bias_wd_mult': 'auto', 'use_lr_scheduler': 'true', 'lr_scheduler_step': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_factor': 'auto', 'lr_scheduler_minimum_lr': 'auto', 'positive_example_weight_mult': '1.0', 'balance_multiclass_weights': 'false', 'normalize_data': 'False', 'normalize_label': 'auto', 'unbias_data': 'auto', 'unbias_label': 'auto', 'num_point_for_scaler': '10000', '_kvstore': 'auto', '_num_gpus': 'auto', '_num_kv_servers': 'auto', '_log_level': 'info', '_tuning_objective_metric': '', 'early_stopping_patience': '3', 'early_stopping_tolerance': '0.001', '_enable_profiler': 'false', 'predictor_type': 'regressor'}
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 WARNING 140601654445888] Loggers have already been setup.
Process 7 is a worker.
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 INFO 140601654445888] Using default worker.
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 INFO 140601654445888] Checkpoint loading and saving are disabled.
[06/16/2024 05:04:57 ERROR 140601654445888] Customer Error: No iterator has been registered for ContentType ('csv', '1.0')

2024-06-16 05:05:13 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2024-06-16 05:05:13 Failed - Training job failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[278], line 1
----> 1 lr_model.fit(data_channel)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py:346, in runnable_by_pipeline.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    342         return context
    344     return _StepArguments(retrieve_caller_name(self_instance), run_func, *args, **kwargs)
--> 346 return run_func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py:1346, in EstimatorBase.fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
   1344 self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
   1345 if wait:
-> 1346     self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py:2703, in _TrainingJob.wait(self, logs)
   2701 # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   2702 if logs != "None":
-> 2703     self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   2704 else:
   2705     self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:5797, in Session.logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)
   5776 def logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait=False, poll=10, log_type="All", timeout=None):
   5777     """Display logs for a given training job, optionally tailing them until job is complete.
   5778 
   5779     If the output is a tty or a Jupyter cell, it will be color-coded
   (...)
   5795         exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException: If waiting and the training job fails.
   5796     """
-> 5797     _logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:8026, in _logs_for_job(sagemaker_session, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)
   8023             last_profiler_rule_statuses = profiler_rule_statuses
   8025 if wait:
-> 8026     _check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   8027     if dot:
   8028         print()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:8079, in _check_job_status(job, desc, status_key_name)
   8073 if "CapacityError" in str(reason):
   8074     raise exceptions.CapacityError(
   8075         message=message,
   8076         allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
   8077         actual_status=status,
   8078     )
-> 8079 raise exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException(
   8080     message=message,
   8081     allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
   8082     actual_status=status,
   8083 )

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job LR-v1-2024-06-16-05-01-56-352: Failed. Reason: ClientError: No iterator has been registered for ContentType ('csv', '1.0'), exit code: 2

